# WebAPI, post one or collection objects to same action without changing message body

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

What I'm trying to do with allow someone to post either:

`[{...}, {...}]  or {...}` to a route and for it to be correctly bound to:

... `Post(IEnumerable<MyModel> models)`

I've got it working fine if I post a collection (`[{...}, {...}]` but I would like it to create a collection with one object when I also post valid json as single object (`{...}`)

The reason I'm trying to do this is because our API works dynamically against a model that is defined by the user at runtime and so I don't know if the uri represents a list or a single resource.

I could achieve this with a customer IModelBinder but I was wondering if there is a way of getting the jsonserializer to deal with this use case without any custom code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to have two API methods call a private method that performs the same logic. For example:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(IEnumerable<MyModel> models)
{
    return DoSomething(models);
}

public HttpResponseMessage Post(MyModel model)
{
    return DoSomething(new List<MyModel> { model });
}

private HttpResponseMessage DoSomething(IEnumerable<MyModel> models)
{
    // Do something
}
```

Web API would figure out which one gets called based on the parameters that get passed in, but both would share the same code under the covers.

**Update:** If your parameters are coming from the body, there are some solutions described here: [How to work with ASP.Net WebApi overloaded methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15813512/how-to-work-with-asp-net-webapi-overloaded-methods)

Comment: Note: This is incorrect. Web API cannot figure this out for parameters coming from body. It can only do this for parameters coming from uri.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately my parameters are coming from the body, not the uri. I will check the link provided!

Comment: It looks like what I'm trying to achieve isn't easily doable. This answer provides the basis for this conclusion.